# Django-import-export doesn't skip unchanged when skip_unchanged==True

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm building an app using Django, and I want to import data from an Excel file using django-import-export.

When importing data I want to skip unchanged rows, for this, I'm using `skip_unchanged = True` in the resource class (like below) but I get unexpected behavior. In my model, I have an attribute `updated_at` which is a `DateTimeField` with `auto_now=True` attribute, it takes a new value each time I upload the Excel file even if the values of rows have not changed in the file.

Below are portions of my code.

**models.py**

```py
class HREmployee(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()  
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=55) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=75) 
    termination_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    hiring_date = models.DateField() 
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    # other fields to be imported from the file ...

    # fields that I want to use for some purposes (not imported from the file)
    comment = models.TextField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**resources.py**

```py
class HREmployeeResource(ModelResource):
    code = Field(attribute='code', column_name='Employee Code')
    name_en = Field(attribute='name_en', column_name='Employee Name - English')
    status = Field(attribute='status', column_name='Employee Status')
    termination_date = Field(attribute='termination_date', column_name='Termination Date')
    hiring_date = Field(attribute='hiring_date', column_name='Hiring Date')
    birth_date = Field(attribute='birth_date', column_name='Birth Date')
    # other fields to be imported ...

    class Meta:
        model = HREmployee
        import_id_fields = ('code', )
        skip_unchanged = True
```

How can I fix this unexpected behavior?

#### Edit

After few tries, I've found that columns with date values are causing this problem.

In the Excel file, I have three columns that have date values like in the picture below, when I comment the corresponding attributes in the resource class and do the import, I get the expected behavior (if no changes in the file the import_type equals skip and no changes are made in the DB).

[image]

I've edited the code of the model and resource classes (please check above).

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to fix, simply use the `fields` parameter to define only the fields you wish to import ([docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options)):

```py
class Meta:
  ...
  fields = ('code', 'name',)
```

If `skip_unchanged` is True, then only these fields will be compared for changes, and the instance will be updated if any one of them has changed, otherwise it will be skipped.

The field name has to be the model attribute name, not the name of the column in the import.

Comment: Nothing changed, I still have the same behavior. Each time I import the file the rows are updated in the DB even if the values of rows have not changed in the file. I have just used two fields (code, name_en) with the `fields` attribute, also this imports all fields even they are not in `fields`.

Comment: Try and run the import in dry run mode and see if that prevents the date from being updated.  Verify that the output says that rows were skipped (not updated)

Comment: I have tried with `dry_run=False` and `dry_run=True`, but nothing changed, I still get the `import_type` equals `update` and the rows in the DB are updated when `dry_run=False`.

Comment: only solution will be to step through with the debugger and find out what's going wrong

Comment: I've found what's causing this problem, it's the date fields. In the file, I have columns with date values and in the model, I have `DateField` to save the values. Any thoughts on how can I fix this?

Comment: can you update the question to provide as much detail as possible about the nature of the problem?

Comment: I've edited the question, please let me know If there is missing detail.

Comment: try to add the `fields` declaration, according to my original answer, if this still doesn't work, use the debugger to identify the issue

Comment: I've found what's causing this problem, it's the timezone of dates. When `django-import-export` retrieves the value of `termination_date` from the DB it has a value like this `2021-02-21 00:00:00+00:00` and it tries to compare with the one imported from the file that looks like this `2021-02-21 00:00:00`. So it finds that are not equals so it returns `False` (this is in the `skip_row` method). Any thought on how can I fix this without disabling `USE_TZ`? (because when I set it to `False` it works as expected)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the revival of that post, but I was stucked on the same issue, and I found only this post exaclty related to, so i post my answer.

In my model I've defined dateField and not DateTimeField.

But it import as DateTimeField, so the comparison failed.

To compare carrots with carrots, I defined a field class to convert values if needed :

```
import datetime
class DateField(Field):
    
    def get_value(self, obj):
        val=super().get_value(obj)
        if isinstance(val, datetime.datetime):
            return val.date()
        return val
```

and then in my resource

class HREmployeeResource(ModelResource):

```
hiring_date = DateField(attribute='hiring_date', column_name='Hiring Date')
birth_date = DateField(attribute='birth_date', column_name='Birth Date')
# ....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use widgets for each field, dont need to do this new class. in the docs you can find it

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html

classimport_export.widgets.DateWidget(format=None)
Widget for converting date fields.

Takes optional format parameter. If none is set, either settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS or "%Y-%m-%d" is used.

so you can do
from import_export.widgets import DateWidget

hiring_date = Field(attribute='hiring_date', column_name='Hiring Date', widget=DateWidget(format='%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: Please try to format your answer correctly, see how do I write a good answer [answer].